# What is the difference in these elasticsearch queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following elasticsearch query that returns plenty of results.

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "swartz",
            "fields": ["notes"]
        }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": {
        "last_modified_date": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to redo it as a bool query so I can add should and must_not, but am getting no results and I'm not sure why.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"term": { "notes": "swartz" }}
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": {
        "last_modified_date": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of results, what I do get is this.

```
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 1,
    "failures" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : ".kibana_1",
        "node" : "E2fjoon_Smm5m7LFcQp9XQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : "No mapping found for [last_modified_date] in order to sort on",
          "index_uuid" : "0pZdhm_nRXWiWGcqFgvvHQ",
          "index" : ".kibana_1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

First, I'm not sure why I get results and it orders properly with the first query, and secondly, even if I take the sort out of the second query I still get no results.

Comment: Are you sure you are executing both the queries on the same index? Can you add mapping of the index specifically for `notes` field.

Comment: And also the `last_modified_date` field, since it's obviously missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you use a match query will look any occurrence of "swartz" somewhere in the content of "notes".

In a SQL world it's something like :

```
where notes ilike "%swartz%"
```

In the second query you use a term query which will look for a perfect equality in the field.
In SQL :

```
 where "notes"=="swartz"
```

It could probably explain your behavior
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Ah yes, that makes complete sense.  I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thanks!